# Android message from BroadcastReceiver to a running TcpSocket Service

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, broadcastreceiver, sendmessage

I am trying to get the SMS intent and pass it to a service that is a TCP socket client, the only problem that I have is that the service can be alive for a maximum of 1000 seconds (I need it up for that long because I can't connect to the phone remotely and I expect some delayed response) and didn't find a way to **send "complex" (string for example) messages to a running service** without binding to them [see this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle)!

The only workarounds that I can think is if I embed the broadcast receiver whithin the service but I'm not quite sure how it works (more specifically if it can be started via broadcastreceiver without anything running) or to have a worker that keeps getting destroyed but it can bind to the service but I feel that's a bit redundant.

I'm really hoping that someone can help and thanks in advance. I'll provide any other information if my question is not clear enough.

Comment: paas your data in the Intent you are passing to startService()

Comment: Well startService is for starting the service right "hint hint" ? How do i send the data while the service is running ?

Comment: After i checked some stuff out and because no one really tells this i i have found out that if you do the startService() when the service is running you call the onStartCommand instead of the onCreate() so yeah :(